# Scope issue in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, scope, drag-and-drop

I'm currently playing around with AngularJS. It starts getting better I hope, but I'm still a bit confused. I created a drag-drop functionality that should keep track of the elments being dropped at the destination, change display values and so on,...
Here is an example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGxwJX

```
As it's a bit much code, I didn't paste it here,...
```

So it allows drag drop with checking if the drop field accepts the type being dragged. After the drop, the element should be recorded in a hashmap called 'items', the 'test' link would then allow to print the items.

When I just drop one item, that seems to work when I click the 'test' link. But dropping another item, the first doesn't get printed anymore. I suspect that there happens something with the scopes I don't understand,...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.handleDrop = function(e) {
  var dataID = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  $scope.$parent.fields[dataID][0] = $scope.$parent.fields[dataID][1];
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();


  $scope.$apply(function() {
    alert(dataID);
    $scope.$parent.items[this.id] = dataID;
    //$scope.$parent.items.push(dataID);
  });

  var item = document.getElementById(dataID);
  var f = eval("$scope.$parent." + item.getAttribute('drop-type'));

  this.innerHTML = '';
  this.appendChild(item);
  this.style.border = "1px solid";
};
```

Your issue is that **this** is changed in scope.$apply(function(){});
So you need assign it to some variable to use it.
Try this, should work;

```
 $scope.handleDrop = function(e) {
  var self = this;
  var dataID = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  $scope.$parent.fields[dataID][0] = $scope.$parent.fields[dataID][1];
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();


  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.$parent.items[self.id] = dataID;
    //$scope.$parent.items.push(dataID);
  });

  var item = document.getElementById(dataID);
  var f = eval("$scope.$parent." + item.getAttribute('drop-type'));

  this.innerHTML = '';
  this.appendChild(item);
  this.style.border = "1px solid";
};
```

Comment: very nice,...how would I know that 'this' is changed in scope.$apply(...)?

Comment: in scope.$apply(function(){}) context is changed, so it refers to global this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$parent.items[this.id] = dataID; will add only the latest one and not all the values.
```

---

You should be having items as an array and push data into it like this:

---

`$scope.$parent.items.push[{this.id,dataID`}];

Comment: Ok, nice. I actually used an array before! And that worked. But,...can you elaborate why that doesn't work the way I tried?oO

Comment: Might be because this.id is same for both your entries, and the second one overwrites the first.

Comment: Naw, the IDs are all different :-/